# How to set up a check on authorized usage of both Invantive Control and Exact Online subscription?

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

Which possibilities are there for setting up a check on the license code or subscription code of both Invantive Control and Exact Online to make sure the user is authorized to use a report?

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain a model of Invantive Control for Excel to only be usable under specific conditions. To protect these setting, you will need to specify a password for editing the model. Otherwise any user can change the license settings and get access.

[image: Configure authorised access on Excel model]